# Angular Image drag and resize

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

hi I have this [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/qrbXecSqvNKcZKUslJ5V?p=preview) that has draggable image what I need is i want to add resizable property

this is my html

```
        Size <input type="number" ng-model="updatesize">
        Position X <input type="number" ng-model="updateX">
        Positon Y <input type="number" ng-model="updateY">
        <div style ="width:900px; height:400px; background-color:red">  

            <img my-resize  my-draggable src="../coffee.jpg" style="width:{{updatesize}}px; top:{{updateY}}px; left:{{updateX}}px; position:relative; cursor:pointer">

        <div>
```

this is my script.js

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
.controller('mainController',['$rootScope', '$scope', function($rootScope, $scope) {



  $scope.updatesize = 250;
  $scope.updateX = 60;
  $scope.updateY = 70;
}])

.directive('myDraggable', ['$document', function($document) {
  return function(scope, element, attr) {
    var startX = 0, startY = 0, x = 0, y = 0;

    element.css({
     position: 'relative',
     width: scope.updatesize + 'px',
     top: scope.updateY + 'px',
     left: scope.updateX + 'px',
     cursor: 'pointer'
    });

    element.on('mousedown', function(event) {
      // Prevent default dragging of selected content
      event.preventDefault();
      startX = event.pageX - x;
      startY = event.pageY - y;
      $document.on('mousemove', mousemove);
      $document.on('mouseup', mouseup);
    });

    function mousemove(event) {
      y = event.pageY - startY;
      x = event.pageX - startX;

      scope.updateX = x;
      scope.updateY = y;

      scope.$apply();

      element.css({
        top: y + 'px',
        left:  x + 'px'
      });
    }

    function resize(event){

    }


    function mouseup() {
      $document.off('mousemove', mousemove);
      $document.off('mouseup', mouseup);
    }
  };
}])
```

when we edit the value in the textbox the image respond to it.

if the resizable is achieved I need to that width pixel value to be the value of size textbox.

could anyone help me please.

Comment: use Raphael JS for this. It is a javascript library that will do all stuff you needed.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you need to capture the startposition of where your actual resize event needs to happen i.e the right-bottom corner of the image,

If your mouse 'down' event is firing at x > image_width - 20 and y > image_height - 20.
then your resize rect will be 40px.

Now you can set a flag isResizing = true and move on to your mouse 'move' event.
Check whether the mouse x,y are getting bigger and update the size.

In the mouse 'up' event set the flag isResizing to false.

Here is a quick example of how you can achieve this:

updated your plunkr: 
plnkr.co/edit/usMgsq?p=preview

You will need to improve this though, but you get the idea